# How to draw a line which looks like a sketched line

Tags: ios, core-graphics

[image]
I need to draw a line using core graphics which looks like the lines in the following image. Is it possible?

Comment: instead of drawing use a image like that

Comment: i need to change the color of the stoke very frequently, so i need to draw it using core graphics.

Comment: You are aware of `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`?